# Text in StackPanel doesn't wrap (wp7)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, grid, stackpanel

I have problem with text wrapping. Without StackPanel this TextBlock works, but i need to put small picture before text. Also I don't have two columns for this (i need only one column for first three rows)

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>  
        <Grid>
             <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                 <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="170"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

             <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>                                   
             <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>                                   
             <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>                                   
             <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Image  Source="Picture.png" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
                  <TextBlock Text="Long long long text from Binding" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="20,10,0,0"  />
             </StackPanel>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `StackPanel` will give its components infinite height or width depending on the `Orientation`.

If I look at your XAML I would suggest to use two columns in the grid, and put the image on the left side:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="170"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Row="3" Source="Picture.png" MaxHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="Long long long text from Binding" FontSize="25" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="20,10,0,0"  />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Notice Grid.ColumnSpan on the first textboxes, this will span them over the entire width of the grid, not just the first column.

Comment: Tested, works! Thanks, I didn't knew about such ColumnSpan option