# TextBlock not wrapping in Grid

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have the following XAML which is meant to show an `Image` and two `TextBlocks` on top of eachother beside it:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Image Source="{Binding CoverArt}" Height="150" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Width="auto">
                <TextBlock FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Summary}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Grid>
         </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

My problem is getting the text to wrap. I've tried using a `Grid` and assigning the columns' width but it didn't work. Neither did setting the width values to auto. The only thing that works is hard-coding the width, but I do not want that. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting the width of the columns to fractions instead? width="2*" That will give you some boundaries without a pixel set size. Some way or another you need to set a constraint for the container. If you have two columns and no size is set they will get 50% each. 2* will make give that column 2/3 of the total column with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Stackpanel will stretch to the size of its content, so it's not what I would use. Use a grid, as explained in the following posts:

[TextBlock TextWrapping not wrapping inside StackPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430705/textblock-textwrapping-not-wrapping-inside-stackpanel)

[Text in StackPanel doesn't wrap (wp7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338044/text-in-stackpanel-doesnt-wrap-wp7)

[TextBlock inside stackpanel does not wrap text](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/6003982d-1b04-4749-84f5-c4a7b22e12bb/textblock-inside-stackpanel-does-not-wrap-text)

A quick comparison:
 **Before with stackpanel**

[image]

**After with one grid** (You might want to rearrange the elements a bit)

[image]

The code for the last segment:

```
<pre>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Fill="red" Width="150" Height="150" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="basdljhba dnaiks d., kasndca casn oiäc cas lkcnaso ca dxjwöbdq wkjöbdqw dkjwqb " TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Width="auto">
                <TextBlock FontSize="22" Text="dewdewdewdewdewewd" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Did you try setting the width of the columns to fractions instead? width="2*" That will give you some boundaries without a pixel set size. Some way or another you need to set a constraint for the container. If you have two columns and no size is set they will get 50% each. 2* will make give that column 2/3 of the total column with, see example below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the images and links helped me understand better :)

Comment: No problem, it's not easy to explain problems (or solutions) online :)

Comment: A much better explanation of the underlying issue than mine. I will delete mine now. Thanks Iris.